# Looking for answer to JavaScript coding quiz

Tags: javascript

```
/*
 * Programming Quiz: One Awesome Message (2-12)
 *
 * 1. Create the variables
 *     - firstName
 *     - interest
 *     - hobby
 * 2. Create a variable named awesomeMessage and, using string concatenation and the variables above, create an awesome message.
 * 3. Print the awesomeMessage variable to the console
 */

    // Add your code here
```

I cannot print the `awesomeMessage` variable to the console to be like this:

> "Hi, my name is Julia. I love cats. In my spare time, I like to play video games."
>   "Hi, my name is James. I love baseball. In my spare time, I like to read."

I am so new to this... please don't judge me. Here is the code I wrote (and am stuck on):

```
 firstName = ["Julia", "James"];
 interest = ["cats", "baseball"];
 hobby = ["play video games", "read"];
var awesomeMessage = "Hi, my name is " + firstName +". " + "I love "+interest+ ". "+ "I like to "+hobby+ ".";
console.log(awesomeMessage);
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: firstName, interests, and hobby are arrays.

Comment: You need to use a loop since your variables are arrays storing two values. Your code would be fine if you were using strings instead of arrays full of strings.

Comment: Your assignment asks for plain variables. You've created arrays. You clearly can't concatenate an array and a string in a single operation. Start over and read the instructions again.

Comment: Sorry to be so noob in this! How would be the code to answer this quiz!

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my answer to use strings instead of arrays. Check out how it compares to what I previously had.

```js
//declaring the variable using var keyword defines the scope
var firstName = "Julia";
var interest = "cats";
var hobby = "play video games";

//concatenate all our vars together into longer string
var awesomeMessage = "Hi, my name is " + firstName + ". " + "I love " + interest + ". " + "I like to " + hobby + ".\n";

//see the result of your string concatenation
console.log(awesomeMessage);
```

Comment: Also note this code would result in an error if all 3 of your arrays are not the same length. This only works because the lengths of the arrays is consistent, otherwise you would probably get some sort or array out of bounds type error.

Comment: Thank you @Tommy O! Yes the code work (I will remember your method) but according to the quiz maker it doesn't work, which mean i guess i don't need arrays. As you mentioned i removed the loop then i got an error!

Comment: Make sure you update your variables to be strings instead of arrays. Next, since you already commented out the loop, make sure to remove the index position next to the variable name! For example `firstName[i]` would become `firstName`.

Comment: with parentheses it will print **James**, and just a string will print **Julia**. Is there any other way around ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tommy O. Now, i need to print *Julia* and *James*, thats my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also taking this nano degree course and got stuck here too. I'm not sure if you figured it out or not, but you have to create your own example from your own answers. Make up your own variables about yourself and create a string from that.

```
/*
 * Programming Quiz: One Awesome Message (2-12)
 *
 * 1. Create the variables
 *     - firstName
 *     - interest
 *     - hobby
 * 2. Create a variable named awesomeMessage and, using string concatenation and the variables above, create an awesome message.
 * 3. Print the awesomeMessage variable to the console
 */

// Add your code here

var firstName = "fname";
var interest = "programming";
var hobby = "reading";
var awesomeMessage = "Hi, my name is "+firstName+". I love "+interest+". In my spare time, I like to "+hobby+".";

console.log(awesomeMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstName = ["Julia", "James"]
var interest = ["cats", "baseball"]
var hobby = ["play video games", "read"]

var awesomeMessage = "Hi, my name is " + firstName [0] + ". " + "I love " + interest[0] + ". " + "In my spare time, I like to " + hobby[0] + ".\n" 
+ "Hi, my name is " + firstName[1] + ". " + "I love " + interest[1] + ". " + "In my spare time, I like to " + hobby[1] + "." ;

console.log (awesomeMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the challenge wants you to be specific to the period(.):

```
var awesomeMessage = "Hi, my name is " + firstName + ". " + "I love " + interest + ". " + "In my spare time, I like to " + hobby + ".";
```

console.log(awesomeMessage);

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstName = ['Julia','James'];
var interest = ['cats','baseball'];
var hobby = ['play video games','read'];
var awesomeMessage = '\"Hi, my name is '+ firstName[0] + '. I love ' + 
interest[0] + '. In my spare time, I like to' + hobby[0] +'.\"\n\"Hi, my name 
is ' + firstName[1] + '. I love ' + interest[1] + '. In my spare time, I like 
to ' + hobby[1] + '.\"';
console.log(awesomeMessage);
```